# How to handle custom names of columns, username and password in laravel authentication

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a table called `logindetials` with the following columns

```
Login_Id | Login_Name | Login_Passwor | Login_Email | .......
```

When I try to authenticate , It results an error, which is given below

```
Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'username' in 'where 
clause' (SQL: select * from `logindetails` where `username` = admin limit 1)
```

I had tried these in config/auth.php

```
'table' => 'logindetails',
'username' => 'Login_Name',
'password' => 'Login_Passwor',
```

and in models/User.php

```
protected $fillable=array('Login_Name','Login_Passwor','Login_Email',...);
protected $primaryKey = "Login_Id";
protected $table = 'logindetails';
protected $hidden = array('Login_Passwor');
public function getAuthIdentifier()
{
    return $this->getKey();
}
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->Login_Passwor;
}
public function getReminderEmail()
{
    return $this->Login_Email;
}
```

and also in login controller

```
if (Input::server("REQUEST_METHOD") == "POST") {

  $validator=Validator::make
            (Input::all(), ["userid" => "required","password" => "required"]);
  if ($validator->passes()) {

     $credentials = [
          "Login_Name" => Input::get("userid"),
          "Login_Passwor" => Input::get("password")];
     if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
          return Redirect::route("/");
     }

  }
  $data["errors"] = new MessageBag(["password" => 
                     ["Username and/or password invalid."]]);
  $data["Login_Name"] = Input::get("userid");
  return Redirect::route("login")->withInput($data);

}
```

But no raksha.
Please somebody help me out from this

Comment: Oh wait, I see you are passing Login_Name. However, password should stay password and not Login_Passwor. That gets set in your model.

Comment: Then I have a doubt, how the error about username will come. If that, then error comes must about password field. Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When authenticating, you need to change username to Login_Name, however, password needs to stay password:

`Auth::attempt( array('Login_Name' => $username, 'password' => $password) )`

Take a look at this file for better understanding of how the User is retrieved when Authenticating: https://github.com/illuminate/auth/blob/master/EloquentUserProvider.php#L60

Comment: Are you sure you are at the correct controller? The above example should work... The array key sets the fields for the Where Clause...

Comment: yes i am sure about the controller. I will echo before that statement

Comment: Try only adding the Auth::Attempt in the controller and remove the other code, and see if it still gives the same error? It might be another function?

Comment: Ah great! Just an extra note. All items passed in the array for your Auth::attempt will form part of the where clause. So if you would like to find a user by Login_Name and Login_Email, you can simply do:
`Auth::attempt( array('Login_Name' => $username, 'Login_email' => $email, 'password' => $password) );`
The 'password' field gets set in your User Model, which you have done. So I believe everything should work.
Please remember to upvote the answer if it has helped you! :)

Comment: Omg your are a wizard. I have been pulling out my hairs for hours.

Answer (score 7):

Actually There is otherway around using which you can keep custom password field.

Just Do Following :

Pretending that you want custom password password as 'Login_Passwor'. For this just add one more function in models\User.php as follows

```
public function getAuthPassword() 
{
   return $this->Login_Passwor; 
}
```

Now in your login controller just make this change for Auth:attempt

```
$credentials = ["Login_Name" => Input::get("userid"),
                "password" => Input::get("password")];

if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) 
{
    return Redirect::route("/");
}
```

This method will work for sure , have tried it